# Confusion with theory between the differences of Node.js servers and PHP servers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, server

I have been able to write apps in both node.js and php for a while now, however only really discovered a weird difference that I feel I still do not entirely understand.

The difference I think I have noticed is that assuming we have to clients visiting a web app run by php, they will have two completely difference instances of all data on the backend (variables arrays, etc). Where as in node.js, they don't quite.

Here is a test I did to try and save some confusion:

## PHP test

frontend js

```
$.post("/ajax.php", {test:"test"}, function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

ajax.php

```
$testarr = array();

if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    $testarr[] = $_POST['test'];
    print_r($testarr);
}
```

...In this example, if i visit the app in two different browsers, or even in the same client, the frontend console will always output an array with a single element in it. So the array essentially resets on refresh obviously/new request.

## Node.js test

frontend js

```
$.post("/test", {test:"test"}, function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

app.js

```
var testarr = [];
app.post("/test", function(req, res){
    testarr.push(req.body.test);
    console.log(testarr);
});
```

Here, however, when i refresh the page even from different browsers, the array does not reset and I end up with ["test", "test", "test", etc] on each request. How can two different clients from two different browsers access the same array like this? usually data has to be shared via a database,special requests, etc right?

I am clearly misunderstanding some big philosophy with node.js and I would appreciate anyone with a nice explanation.

Comment: in node JS, you "keep running". a variable is just a variable, just like on the page, it's around until you reload. that's why node is so much better at a lot of tasks than php: it doesn't need nearly the per-connection overhead of apache+php. it's also why you need to be careful about how you pass private data around.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that PHP creates a new environment for each request while node.js doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not the biggest PHP gury but I think you overwrite your PHP array instead of pushing new elements in. You can use array_push() to add something to your testarr.

Comment: $testarr[] = "test" does the same :)

Comment: In that case I was wrong :) . Thanks for the correction!